# Centering Logo on Responsive site

Tags: center

I would like the logo and the image slider to center on my responsive site.

Basically, the logo and the slider are next to each other on a full size screen. I can make the slide disappear when the site isn't wide enough and the logo shrinks.

What I want to do is make the logo and the slider center once they are no longer next to each other.

Please help: http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can center the child elements of `hgroup` tag by setting `margin: 0 auto;text-align:center` on the `hgroup`

this will cause the contents to be centered within that div

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

CSS:
`
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 hgroup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
 }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Put the logo and slider in a div and give it a fixed width. If this div has #inner id, the solution will be:

```
#inner {
width:1000px;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the given answers will only work if you use both of them, centring with margin: 0 auto; only works if  a width is specified, and having a div just display as a block will not change the appearance.
Try the css:

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;  }
```

along with other styling, and it should center